# setText causing application to crash

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm new to android development. I can't figure out why this is crashing in the emulator, When i run this program on my Android emulator it opens then quickly closes giving me a "Unfortunately hello world has stopped message.

```
            public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
                /** Called when the activity is first created. */
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                    TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
                    t.setText("Secoknd text to display!"); 

                }   
            }
```

xml file :

```
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >





                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:editable="true"
                    android:text="TextView" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
            10-20 20:07:48.784: D/AndroidRuntime(601): Shutting down VM
            10-20 20:07:48.784: W/dalvikvm(601): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409951f8)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helloandroid/com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroidActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroidActivity.onCreate(HelloAndroidActivity.java:16)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
            10-20 20:07:48.804: E/AndroidRuntime(601):  ... 11 more
            10-20 20:12:48.894: I/Process(601): Sending signal. PID: 601 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Provide the error from LogCat and you'll get a very quick answer

Comment: Is it generating a `NullPointerException`? Run this code through a debugger and check if `t` is `null` before invoking `setText`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the TextView is null with the code you provided, you must be setting the wrong layout id.  Your code sample has `setContentView(R.layout.main);`.  Is it possible that the xml you provided is from a file other than main.xml?

Comment: it seems that main.xml in layout folder different that layout-normal. I just copied one file into the other and now it works, what is the difference between the two folders and does the main.xml have to be the same in both? thanks!

Comment: you can have different folders for different device types and screen sizes.  the system will choose the resource based on the device running your code.  when no specialized folder exists, the system falls back to layout/.  I think layout-normal overrides this folder when it exists.  This is described in the following link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

If you designed more then one layout file for different screen size must named same id. if the id mismatches this will happen.

for example

```
    public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
        t.setText("Secoknd text to display!"); 
        }   
    }
```

Layout/main.xml

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="38dp"
     android:editable="true"
     android:text="TextView" />
```

Layout-large-hdpi/main.xml

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="38dp"
     android:editable="true"
     android:text="TextView" />
```

If you run on an ldpi mobile it works. but if you run on an hdpi mobile it cant find